# Text input wildly off center in emulator, is it normal?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-emulator

[image: input displays strange in emulator, down and left of center]

In Android emulators running API 19, for some reason, the input placed into EditText controls is strangely off-centered downwards and to the left, in some cases almost to the point that they are not visible.  I was wondering if this is just a common bug that is usually ignored or if anybody could suggest a cause and/or solution to fix this, as I do not have any physical devices running this version of android and cannot test it myself outside of the emulator.

In case it is relevant, here is the xml for the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mydevelopername.myapp.thisactivityname"
    android:background="#005b96">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout5">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/lbl_volume_ivdrip"
                android:id="@+id/lbl_volume"
                android:textColor="#b3cde0"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/txt_volume"
                android:background="#6497b1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_volume"
                android:background="#6497b1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/lbl_drip_set"
                android:id="@+id/lbl_drip_set"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#b3cde0" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_drip_set"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:background="#6497b1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/lbl_infuse_time"
                android:id="@+id/lbl_infuse_time"
                android:textColor="#b3cde0"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/txt_infuse_time"
                android:background="#6497b1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_infuse_time"
                android:background="#6497b1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_ivdrip_result"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#b3cde0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#b3cde0"
        android:textColor="#011f4b"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_ivdrip_result"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="ivdrip_calc" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to get started with Android development and am unfamiliar with some of the commonalities that may exist in this platform that pertain to issues with these emulators.  So, please accept my apology if this turns out to be a silly question.  Thanks!

Comment: For each EditText, use the attribute `android:gravity="start"` to position the text at the beginning.

Comment: Great! Thanks!  That worked out quite well.

Comment: I have added it as an answer. If this solved your problem you can accept it so others can see. Happy coding!

Comment: Great!  Just did..  Thanks a mil, buddy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position your `EditText` input text, use the attribute `android:gravity="X"` where `X` is the keyword for where you want it positioned. In your case, use `start` to position it at the beginning.